# How to prove if functions are one to one or onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I know generally if you want to prove the function is one to one you just have to check for

$f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$ and to check if it is onto you just have to show that $f(x)=y$ and $y$ has to be unique.

But generally this is dealt with only two variables where one variable is equal to another, but how do you deal with two variables.

For example,

$f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z}$
and $(m,n) \rightarrow 2m+n$.

What is getting me is the two variables in the function and the $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of the function is $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$. the elements of the domain are of the form $(a,b)$. you just have to check whether $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ implies $(a,b)=(c,d)$ in this case it is false since $f(0,0)=f(-1,2)$. So the function is not injective.

You can see it is surjective because if you take an element of the co-domain (In this case $\mathbb Z$, so an integer $k$) you can see that $f(0,k)=2(0)+k=k$. So every element of the co-domain is the image of at least one element of the domain.

Comment: I understand the surjective but for the injective, did you just pick any (a,b) from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and then plug it in for the function 2m+n?

Comment: no, I looked for an example of two different elements of the domain that map to the same element of the codomain.

Comment: i see. thanks! that makes sense